# How can I find the index in nested array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, javascript-objects

I have a nested array of objects named `dishes` which has unique IDs in it. I want to find the index of the array if the `id` is present in `foodItems` in `dishes` and then remove it from `foodItems`

```
const dishes = [{
        cuisine: 'Chinese',
        foodItems: [{
                id: '1',
                dishName: 'Chicken noodles',
                price: '6.00 USD'
            },
            {
                id: '2',
                dishName: 'Fried rice',
                price: '5.00 USD'
            },
            {
                id: '3',
                dishName: 'Dumplings',
                price: '2.00 USD'
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        cuisine: 'Indian',
        foodItems: [{
                id: '4',
                dishName: 'Tikka masala',
                price: '10.00 USD'
            },
            {
                id: '5',
                dishName: 'Naan Bread',
                price: '2.00 USD'
            },
            {
                id: '6',
                dishName: 'Dal Fry',
                price: '4.00 USD'
            }
        ],
    }
];
```

Here, is what I tried (Which is not working and returning `undefined` in `index`):

```
let removeId = (id) => {
    let index = dishes.forEach(dish => dish.foodItems.findIndex(item => item.id === id)); // returns undefined
    if (index !== -1) {
        dishes.forEach(dish=> dish.foodItems.splice(index, 1)); // remove obj from foodItems array
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the rest of your logic in the `forEach()` callback method. However, taking into account that you want to return `true` once the item has been removed, it's easier to use a `for ... of` loop:

```js
const dishes = [{
    cuisine: 'Chinese',
    foodItems: [{
        id: '1',
        dishName: 'Chicken noodles',
        price: '6.00 USD'
      },
      {
        id: '2',
        dishName: 'Fried rice',
        price: '5.00 USD'
      },
      {
        id: '3',
        dishName: 'Dumplings',
        price: '2.00 USD'
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    cuisine: 'Indian',
    foodItems: [{
        id: '4',
        dishName: 'Tikka masala',
        price: '10.00 USD'
      },
      {
        id: '5',
        dishName: 'Naan Bread',
        price: '2.00 USD'
      },
      {
        id: '6',
        dishName: 'Dal Fry',
        price: '4.00 USD'
      }
    ],
  }
];

const removeId = (id) => {
    for (let dish of dishes) {
        const index = dish.foodItems.findIndex(fi => fi.id === id);
        if (index > -1) {
          dish.foodItems.splice(index, 1);
          return true;
        }
    };
    return false;
}

console.log(removeId('1'));
console.log(removeId('4'));
console.log(removeId('7'));

console.log(dishes);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps. But, I also want to return a boolean `true` once splice operation is successful and if not then `false`. When I try adding `return true` to your answer at the end of `if` statement and do a `console.log(removeId('1'))` it prints `undefined`. Is there a way to return `true` after splice?

Comment: @shariksid Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you this answers my question! I have accepted it :) Also, just for learning purpose I'm trying to remove the complete object from `dishes` if there are no objects present in `foodItems` after splice operation. Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, using a for of and add entries variable what you for loop

```
const dishes = [
  {
    cuisine: "Chinese",
    foodItems: [
      {
        id: "1",
        dishName: "Chicken noodles",
        price: "6.00 USD",
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        dishName: "Fried rice",
        price: "5.00 USD",
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        dishName: "Dumplings",
        price: "2.00 USD",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    cuisine: "Indian",
    foodItems: [
      {
        id: "4",
        dishName: "Tikka masala",
        price: "10.00 USD",
      },
      {
        id: "5",
        dishName: "Naan Bread",
        price: "2.00 USD",
      },
      {
        id: "6",
        dishName: "Dal Fry",
        price: "4.00 USD",
      },
    ],
  },
];

for (const [idx, items] of dishes.entries()) {
  console.log(items.foodItems)
}
```

for the documentation in here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: Will just throw an error and will not come even close to achieving the stated requirements.